# AttributeError: 'SparkSession' object has no attribute 'time'

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark

I am carrying out an SQL query and want to be able to print out how long it takes for the query to execute. I keep getting an Attribute Error saying Spark Session has no attribute time. I have been doing the following :

```
>>> df2 = sqlContext.sql("select * from temptable where Location == 'Moorland Rd Library'")
>>> spark.time(df2.show())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'SparkSession' object has no attribute 'time'
```

Comment: I'm assuming somewhere in your code is `from apachespark import SparkSession as spark`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1  have done that but still does not work :

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession as spark

Answer (score 2):

Like someone else mentioned, `SparkSession.time()` it's not available in pyspark. A simple solution would be to use `time`:

```
import time
start_time = time.time()
df2.show()
print(f"Execution time: {time.time() - start_time}")
```

Answer (score 0):

`SparkSession.time()` function is available only in scala. For python, you can instead use `time` module.

```
import time
time(df2.show())
```